# Holomorphic functions of the form $f'(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, delay-differential-equations

> Question: Let $R = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \colon |\Re(z)|, |\Im(z)| < 1\}$. Determine all functions $f\colon R \to \mathbb{C}$ that are holomorphic in $R$ and satisfies
> $$f'(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})},\ \text{for all}\ z \in R.$$

My attempt: Claim that the only functions are of the form $A e^z$ where $A \in \mathbb{C}$. Suppose $f$ is such a function, then $f$ is analytic in $R$ and it admits a unique power series representation at $z=0$ that is $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ for all $z \in R$ where $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ for all $n =0,1,2,\dots$. By the identity we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1} (n+1) z^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{a_n} z^n$ for all $z \in R$. By uniqueness of the power series, $\overline{a_n} = a_{n+1} (n+1)$ for all $n =0,1,2,\dots$, where the radius of convergence is precisely $\infty$. However, I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: 1. (minor point)  The series need not converge on the whole of $R$   2. Why is the radius of convergence $0$?

Comment: Aren't holomorphic functions equivalent to complex-analytic functions, so the power-series defined at $0$ should be well-defined at all points in $R$. My mistake the radius should be $\infty$ since $r = \lim_n |a_n/ a_{n+1}| = \infty$.

Comment: Every entire function has $R=\infty$. How did you conclude that $f=0$?

Comment: $f(z)=e^{z}$ satisfies the requirements.

Comment: @geetha290krm you are right!

Comment: And $f(z)=ae^z + ibe^{-z}$ also does for real $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Proceed by considering $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ separately via the recursion you found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With $C = a_0 = f(0)$ the recursion formula $a_{n+1} = \overline{a_n}/(n+1)$ gives $a_n = C/n!$ for even $n$, and $a_n = \overline C/n!$ for odd $n$. Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
 f(z) &= C + \frac{\overline C}{1!}z + \frac{C}{2!}z^2 + \frac{\overline C}{3!}z^3 +  \frac{C}{4!}z^4 + \frac{\overline C}{5!}z^5 +\cdots \\
&= C\left(1 + \frac{1}{2!}z^2 + \frac{1}{4!}z^4 + \cdots\right)
+ \overline C\left(z + \frac{1}{3!}z^3 + \frac{1}{5!}z^5 + \cdots\right) \\
&= C \cdot \cosh(z) + \overline C \cdot \sinh(z) \, .
\end{align}
$$
You can also write it as
$$
 f(z) = C \cdot \frac{e^z + e^{-z}}{2} + \overline C\cdot \frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2} 
 = \operatorname{Re}(C) \cdot e^z + i \operatorname{Im}(C)\cdot  e^{-z} \, ,
$$
or $f(z) = a e^z + ibe^{-z}$ with $a, b \in \Bbb R$.

---

If you are familiar with the basic theory of linear differential equations with constant coefficients then you can also argue as follows: Differentiating $f'(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ gives
$$
f''(z) = \overline{f'(\overline{z})} = f(z) \, ,
$$
so $f$ is a solution of the ordinary differential equation (ODE)
$$
 w'' - w = 0 \, .
$$

Both $(e^z , e^{-z})$ and $(\cosh(z), \sinh(z))$ are pairs of linearly independent solutions of that ODE, so that $f$ is necessarily a linear combination of those functions.